# Delete Words from a String Array based on Words of Another String Array in C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to write a C program to delete some words from an Array of String (chars) in C programming based on another Array of String (chars).

I have written a program like the following.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

void main()
{
    int i, j, k, flag;
char Name[200][100] = {"descent","of","man","the","ascent","of","man","the","old","man","and","the","sea","a","portrait","of","the","artist","as","a","young","man"};
char Delete[200][100] = {"the","of","and","as","a"};

printf("Words are : \n\n");
for (i = 0; i<22; i++)
{
    printf("%s, ", Name[i]);
}

printf("\n\nWords for deletion are: \n\n");

for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    printf("%s, ", Delete[i]);
}

printf("\n\n");


for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    flag = 0;

    for(j=0; j<22; j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(Name[i],Delete[j]) == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (flag == 1)
        {
            for (k = j; k<22-1; k++)
            {
                strcpy(Name[k],Name[k+1]);
            }

            strcpy(Name[22-1],"");
        }
    }
}

printf("Words after deletion is : \n\n");

for (i = 0; i<22; i++)
{
    printf("%s ", Name[i]);
}

printf("\n");
}
```

But unfortunately, the program is not working as desired. I am not understanding what I am doing wrong in here. Can anyone please suggest me what I am doing wrong in here or an easier way of doing it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain more of what are you trying to do exactly?!

Comment: There are two character type arrays. I am trying to delete the words from the first array based on the second one.

For example, both the arrays contain "of". So "of" will be removed from the first array. @Samer

Comment: How is this C++? Please tag responsibly!

Comment: I am still learning and I don't know how to use Vector. So, I am trying to do it using array. @CaptainObvlious

Comment: @TanvirSourov you are making your life much harder doing it this way...  you may reset to NULL but I dont think you can delete as the previuos comments mentioned use std::vector...you can check out some tutorials online [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: If this is a C program, then std::vector is not available, it's C++ only.

Comment: Then what should I do? I still can not program in C++. :(

Comment: @TanvirSourov you are on the right track, but you are missing a few things. I'll post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also was able to solve the problem by doing it like the following:

```
len = 22;
for(i=0; i<5; i++)

{
    flag = 0;

for(j=0; j<len; j++)
{
    if(strcmp(Name[j],Delete[i]) == 0)
    {
        for (k = j; k<len-1; k++)
        {
            strcpy(Name[k],Name[k+1]);
        }

        strcpy(Name[len-1],"");
        len--;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  The initial lists have had an empty string added to the end as a sentinel, and the loops have been changed to use the sentinels.  When the string to be deleted is detected, I change the first char to 0x1A (the ASCII control char for "substitution occurred" - chosen somewhat arbitrarily).  Then I walk the word list once, and when I find a sub char, i skip that string and then 'compress out' the deleted words by copying over them from the next non-null string without a sentinel char in it.  I could have used some trickery to avoid the second pass and copy things over in the main loop, but I did not want to over combine the logic for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
   int i, j;
   /* both lists end with a sentinal string of ""  */
   char Name[200][100] = {"descent","of","man","the","ascent","of","man","the","old","man","and","the","sea","a","portrait","of" ,"the","artist","as","a","young","man",""};
   char Delete[200][100] = {"the","of","and","as","a", ""};

   printf("Words are : \n\n");
   for( i=0; Name[i][0] != 0x00; i++ ) {
      printf("%s, ", Name[i]);
   }

   printf("\n\nWords for deletion are: \n\n");
   for( j=0; Delete[j][0] != 0x00; j++ ) {
      printf("%s, ", Delete[j]);
   }
   printf("\n\n");

   /* mark for removal */
   for( i=0; Name[i][0] != 0x00; i++ ) {
      for( j=0; Delete[j][0] != 0x00; j++ ) {
         if(strcmp(Name[i],Delete[j]) == 0) {
            Name[i][0]=0x1A; /* ASCII ctrl char for substitute - chosen arbitrarily */
         }
      }
   }

   /* one pass to remove */
   for( i=0, j=0; Name[i][0] != 0x00; i++,j++ ) {
      while( Name[i][0] == 0x1A )
         i++;

      if(i!=j)
         strcpy(Name[j],Name[i]);
   }
   strcpy(Name[j],Name[i]);

   printf("Words after deletion are: \n\n");

   for( i=0; Name[i][0] != 0x00; i++ ) {
      printf("%s ", Name[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off you need to keep track of the number of elements in each array

```
 size_t numName = 22;
 size_t numDelete = 5;
```

The issue is in the line `for(j=0; j<22; j++)`. When you delete a word in Name, you **must not** increment `j`.

The basic logic isn't too bad as long as you update the number of words in numNames and update `j` correctly.

**UPDATE** I just noticed that you have your indexes for `i` and `j` reversed in `strcmp`. That's another issue.

```
for (i = 0; i < numDelete; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < numName;)
    {
        if (strcmp(Name[j], Delete[i]) == 0)
        {
            for (k = j; k < numName - 1; k++)
            {
                strcpy(Name[k], Name[k+1]);
            }

            strcpy(Name[numName - 1], "");
            numName--; /* After deleting a name, reduce the size of the name array */
        }
        else
        {
            j++; /* Only increment j when not deleting. */
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I also got rid of `flag` it wasn't needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. :) You are really great. :D